# how to make vmousemove work like mousemove

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a small web app where the user writes a character onscreen (mouse or touchscreen) with the coordinates of the drawing saved into an array.

What I have at the moment does what I want it to do in a desktop browser, however on a touchscreen vmousedown and vmouseup are doing what they should but vmousemove seems to behave differently.

Could someone please let me know how i can make vmousemove on a touchscreen, the way that it works in a browser?

Thank you

```
$("#pad").on("vmousemove", function(e) {
    if (e.which === 1) {
        var strokeX = e.pageX
        var strokeY = e.pageY

        if (strokeX - character[strokeno][strokepoint][0] > resolution || character[strokeno][strokepoint][0] - strokeX > resolution || strokeY - character[strokeno][strokepoint][1] > resolution || character[strokeno][strokepoint][1] - strokeY > resolution  )
        {
            ctx.lineTo(strokeX, strokeY);
            ctx.stroke();
            character[strokeno].push([strokeX,strokeY])
            $("#coords").append("X: " + e.pageX + " Y: " + e.pageY);
            strokepoint++
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oof28z8s/